# TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/client/fluent/Async$ExecRunnable.class

Tags: android, android-studio

i am continuously facing this error ,
here is my build grade.....

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. >
>   com.android.build.api.transform,TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   org/apache/http/client/fluent/Async$ExecRunnable.class

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.shubham.rest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes
            {
        release
                {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0"
    compile files('libs/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.5.2.jar')
    compile "com.android.support:design:23.4.0"

}
```

Comment: did your app run ok?

Comment: add `compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3'` instead of your jar & add `android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`

Comment: at first clean & rebuild . then add `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`

Comment: @Intellij Amiya  ...this did not work for me ,i am stilk getting error like this--- Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/client/cache/CacheResponseStatus.class